# How I download a document from a envelop in DocuSign?

Tags: java, rest, docusignapi

I need to download a document from an envelope using the rest services of DocuSign.

The system that I'm working is in Javascript but uses bibles of Java.

I'm doing the call of the method via java.net.URL, and I can't the get the bytes of the file to use on the system.

I tried to read the InputStream returned, but this doesn't return an XML with base64.

```
var url = new java.net.URL('https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/0c2ddaae-e258-4ade-a435-e4ee50fd2542/envelopes/c60565e2-40d9-43f3-bb2d-58e086c20fca/documents/1');
        var connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        
        connection.setRequestProperty("X-DocuSign-Authentication", '{"Username":"user","Password":"password=","IntegratorKey": "guid"}');
        connection.setRequestProperty("content-type", "text/xml;charset=UTF-8");

if(connection.getResponseCode() == 200){
            try{
                var retorno = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                var retData = new java.lang.StringBuilder();
                var line;
                while((line = retorno.readLine()) != null){
                    retData.append(line);
                }
            
                var strData = retData.toString();
```

When I use the SoapUi, I receive this:
JVBERi0xLjQKJfv8/blablalblalblalba

But in my code, I receive something like this:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache Content-Length: 122448
>
> Content-Type: application/pdf X-RateLimit-Reset: 1561921200
>
> X-RateLimit-Limit: 1000 X-RateLimit-Remaining: 955
>
> X-DocuSign-TraceToken: c5710b05-b13c-460f-b04a-1e683471934e
>
> Content-Disposition: file; filename=blank1.pdf; documentid=1 Date:
>
> Sun, 30 Jun 2019 18:51:47 GMT

Answer (score 1):

You use the [EnvelopeDocuments::get](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/get) API method.

See the [code example](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-download-envelope-documents).

See the [Java example implementation](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-java-auth-code-grant/blob/master/src/main/java/com/docusign/controller/examples/EG007ControllerEnvelopeGetDoc.java#L73)

Note that `documentId` can be the id of a specific document in the envelope or one of the reserved values:

- `combined` -- will download a single PDF containing all of the envelope's documents
- `archive` -- will download a zip file.

Your code example implies that you are trying to optimize the download by streaming the data your destination. These days, with cheap memory (real and virtual), I suggest that you simply download the document to memory and then deal with it.

You can later optimize to use streams if necessary.

Comment: Thank you.

I saw this code example, but I can't use the SDK in my system, because it is a closed system.

I did same changes in my code, and I get the binary.

Comment: What I make doens't work. When I call the method, I just receive a part of the file. If I save the file using the binary, it create a blank pdf.

Comment: How I can download the document before to use? I need to do this just using javascript on server side.

Comment: You can implement the API call directly. See the EnvelopeDocuments::get API method listed in my answer. If you would like more help,  I suggest the first step is to implement the API call without using streams. Use a Java HTTPS API library.

Comment: Thank you, but I lost the job because I could not implement.